# Upgrade scenario not working using Installshield 2013

Tags: visual-studio, installshield

I have created installer using install-shield 2013. Installer deploys the file and there is one executable file. I did some changes in executable file and created installer again.

When I upgraded using installer then I found my executable is not replaced with new one.

In Install-shield, I went to "Releases",  go to the "Setup.exe" section and there's a field called "MSI Command Line Arguments" and provided **REINSTALLMODE=emus REINSTALL=ALL** but it did not work.

Please suggest for same.

Regards,
Rashi

Comment: What changes (besides the code) did you make to your exe? What changes did you make to your installer? (Namely, did you increase the file version of your exe, and what kind of upgrade did you create for the msi?) Examining a verbose log may help you to understand why the file was not updated.

Comment: I added some code in exe but did not increase the file version of exe. There were no changes in installer. Do i need to increase\add file version in assemblyInfo.cs file ?

Comment: Yeah, see [File Versioning Rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368599). Relying on REINSTALLMODE=emus is at best a hack; what did the verbose log say about it not addressing your symptoms?

Comment: I increased the assemble version of executable and created installer again without REINSTALLMODE=emus but exe was not replaced when upgraded using installer. Please suggest what steps need to follow.